# yield return new WaitForSeconds not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 instances of this IEnumerator on 2 scripts. Both are private, but one is working, the other isn't.

This is the first one that is working:

```
private IEnumerator EndGame()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

This is the second one that isn't working:

```
private IEnumerator EndGame()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

They're exactly the same. I can call the IEnumerator (proven by a Debug.Log), but in one case it waits for 3 seconds, and in the other one it stops at the return statement and doesn't continue. I also tried renaming the Coroutine that wasn't working and making them both private just in case you can't have Coroutines with the same name, but that also didn't work. My time scale is constantly remaining at 1 and the object that I called the Coroutine from doesn't get destroyed.

One weird thing that does happen is the object that I call the Coroutine from does get destroyed, but after the 3 seconds is up (The highlighted player is the one calling the Coroutine, and the same thing happens on both players):

[image: Example GIF]

Comment: How are you calling these functions?

Comment: StartCoroutine("EndGame");

Comment: as both functions are the same, and indeed the same name, why are you not calling just the one function? why would you have 2 the same?

Comment: They need to be on separate scripts

Comment: Trying to follow the [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle: why do you need the same code in two different places? Make it accessible to both.

Comment: Coroutines don't execute on destroyed gameobjects.  It doesn't matter what object starts the coroutine, what matters is the object that implements it.  This is because unity coroutines execute as part of the script lifycycle. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: I need the code in 2 places because it's objects in 2 different scenes and the coroutine is executing on an active gameobject.

Comment: different scenes and different objects doesnt mean it cant be the same script! there isnt enough info here for us to advise whats wrong.. you need to debug

Comment: Can you post the exact piece of code you use to call both of these functions? That would help to get a better picture of what's happening. I never call a coroutine with a string, personally I'd do it like StartCoroutine(EndGame());

Comment: You don't _need_ it in two places, that's just a design decision you have made.  you'd probably be better served having a "Game Controller" object which hosts the _single_ instance of `EndGame()` that your other scripts call/notify.

Comment: One thing that you may not be aware of is that coroutines are not true multi-threading.  They still run on the main thread in linear (consecutive) fashion.  As Leo said above, if the game object hosting the coroutine is destroyed, the coroutine is aborted.

Comment: Yes the gameobject isn't destroyed during the coroutine. The gameobject does get destroyed after the coroutine is called mysteriously. I think it has to do with the object detecting a change in scenes, but nothing else detects the change. I can't have one unanimous game controller because this is the only function that's common between the two game modes. I can call the coroutine either way, it doesn't matter.